# Jquery command not executing, can't see what I'm doing wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to access random quotes through an API using Jquery. I am very new to this so I'm sure there is a simple solution that I cannot see. Basically this is my HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <button id="quoteClick" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg quoteButton text-center btn-block">Get Quote</button>
</div>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 show boxed text-center">
      Text
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
    </div>
  </div>
```

My JS is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#quoteClick").on("click", function() {
    $.getJSON("https://crossorigin.me/http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en", function(json) {
      var html = "";

        json.forEach(function(x) {

          html += "<div class = 'quote'>";


          html += "<h3 '" + x.quoteText + "' "+ "'>";

          html += "</div>";

        });

        $(".show").html(html);

      });
    });
  });
```

When I use console.log(json) I can print the object I'm querying from, but when I actually try to fish out a quote and print it on my web page nothing happens. I am using codepen.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: @Aperson no, I just get nothing.

Comment: What do you expect `forEach` should do?  What do you expect `x` to hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be iterating over the object you get from the API. If you look at a single API call, one result I got looked like this:

```
{
  "quoteText": "To be thoughtful and kind only takes a few seconds compared to the timeless hurt caused by one rude gesture.",
  "quoteAuthor": "Byron Pulsifer",
  "senderName": "",
  "senderLink": "",
  "quoteLink": "http:\/\/forismatic.com\/en\/4255d6ba93\/"
}
```

You just need to drop the forEach call, and your code will work.

Also (gavgrif noted this first in their answer), your HTML is malformed - you should have the text inside the h3.

This should be better:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#quoteClick").click(function() {
        $.getJSON("https://crossorigin.me/http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en", function(json) {
            var html = "";
            html += "<div class = 'quote'>";
            html += "<h3>" + json.quoteText + "</h3>";
            html += "</div>";
            $(".show").html(html);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: ^That works. I just tested it in an [fiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/difster/qvbs6ps4/).

Comment: @APerson Thanks that worked! If you don't mind, why was the forEach call not appropriate?

Comment: @arziankorpen forEach is used for arrays. The API response (which I included at the top) has no arrays; it's just an object.

Comment: good answer - and since the issues I raised have been corrected - I will delete my answer for the sake of clarity in this page. Cheers :)